# SQL Loading Data But Missing First Section

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'students.csv' INTO TABLE students FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (studentid,fname,mname,lname,psuid,state,country,major);
```

Query OK, 997 rows affected, 2276 warnings (0.02 sec)
Records: 997  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 2276

[students table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKpA.png)

After loading my data into the table my first part of the data was missing the first name is gone. Which is why the major section is empty and everything is shifted over.

Please help! Thank you :)

[CSV image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpSGp.png)

Comment: Can you show an example of CSV row ?

Comment: okay. i added it in the post.

Comment: Use formatted text instead. (Skip the images, we can't see them anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed studentid column is defined with AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. You should remove definition of studentid in your `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement and let MySQL auto generate it.

Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'students.csv'
INTO TABLE students
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(fname,mname,lname,psuid,state,country,major);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data in the file does not seem to be in the correct order.